# Ambiguous error thrown by R

Tags: r

No missing values.

**Source**

```
df_old$transformed <- log(df_old$x, exp)
```

**Console**

```
df_old$transformed <- log(as.numeric(as.character(df_old$x)),exp)
```

> Error in log(as.numeric(as.character(df_old$x)), exp) :    non-numeric
>   argument to mathematical function

```
is.numeric(df_old$x)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the function `exp` as the second argument to `log`, when what you want is an evaluated call to `exp`;

```r
# Second argument is a function
log(2, base = exp)
#> Error in log(2, base = exp): non-numeric argument to mathematical function

# Second argument is a numeric
log(2, base = exp(1))
#> [1] 0.6931472
```